# Cannot delete orphaned domain group from permissions on ESXi

Tags: active-directory, vmware-esxi

I have an AD domain joined ESXi server (v7.0 U2) that does not longer have a connection to its AD domain. When trying to remove it from the domain, it fails with:

```
Failed to leave the domain domain.tld: The user or group named 'DOMAIN\mygroup' does not exist.
```

The group `DOMAIN\mygroup` is a group from AD that I used to grant permissions on the ESXi host. It looks like the host is not able to remove the AD group from permissions.

When I try to remove the group manually through vSphere web client, I get a `vim.fault.UserNotFound` error.

When I try to remove the group through ESXi CLI, with:

```
 esxcli system permission unset --group --id=DOMAIN\\mygroup
```

I get the error `The user or group named 'DOMAIN\mygroup' does not exist.`

How can I remove such orphaned domain groups from ESXi permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete those groups with the following workaround:

1. Login to your ESXi via SSH.
2. Create a local group with exactly the same name as the orphaned group (case sensitive):

   ```
   /usr/lib/vmware/busybox/bin/busybox addgroup DOMAIN\\mygroup
   ```
3. Then you are able to delete the group from permissions.
4. Remove the local group afterwards:

   ```
   /usr/lib/vmware/busybox/bin/busybox delgroup DOMAIN\\mygroup
   ```